# How to get sed to anonymize all e-mail addresses in file

Tags: regex, sed

I'm looking for a way to replace all e-mail addresses in a file with xxx@xxx.xxx 
I guess sed is the right tool for the job, but I'm unable to find the way to do it in a robust and correct way. Thanks.

Comment: How does your input file look like?

Comment: Since you say "robust" and "correct" way...keep in mind that [the correct regular expression to match email addresses according to the RFC is 6.2 kb big (sic)](http://www.ex-parrot.com/~pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html).

Answer (score 4):

Here is one crude way of doing that using `sed -r`:

```
sed -r 's/^(.*? |)[^@]+@[^ ]+/\1xxx@xxx.xxx/g' file
```

On BSD (eg OSX) use this variant:

```
sed -E 's/(^|.* )[^@]+@[^ ]+/\1xxx@xxx.xxx/g' file
```

Though keep in mind email addresses can vary a lot these days.

Comment: What is `\b`? I could not find anything about it in the documentation, see here http://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix/unix-regular-expressions.htm.

Comment: Thanks telling me about `\t`! But does your RegExp really work? It tries to find an address starting with an arbitrary repetition of `@`-characters, followed by a `.` and other stuff ... ?

Comment: @cars10: Please provide a small sample of your input file in your question so that I can investigate and edit if needed.

Comment: `a@b.c` -> `a@xxx@xxx.xxx`

Comment: @Kevin: Actually I just tried: `sed -r 's/^(.*? |)[^@]+@[^ ]+/\1xxx@xxx.xxx/g' <<< 'a@b.c'` and got `xxx@xxx.xxx`

Comment: With your new one, clearly. And that one gave me `error: repetition-operator operand invalid` on BSD sed (where you need `-E` instead of `-r`, btw.) I believe it's referring to the lazy `.*?`

Comment: @Kevin: On BSD (eg OSX) following works: `sed -E 's/^(.*)[^@]+@[^ ]+/\1xxx@xxx.xxx/g' <<< 'a@b.c'`

Comment: @Kevin: I have provided a BSD alternative command in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

The following worked for me:

```
sed "s/[^@ ]*@[^@]*\.[^@ ]*/xxx@xxx.xx/g" file
```

applied on the following `file`

```
charly.chaplin@web.de has an address
so has axel.springer@bild.de
and finally henry@kissinger.info and other stuff
```

The command `C:\Temp>d:sed "s/[^@ ]*@[^@]*\.[^@ ]*/xxx@xxx.xx/g" file` gets me this:

```
xxx@xxx.xx has an address
so has xxx@xxx.xx
and finally xxx@xxx.xx and other stuff
```

Answer (score 1):

This obfuscates email-adresses partially:

```
sed -E 's/[a-zA-Z0-9_][a-zA-Z0-9_][a-zA-Z0-9_][a-zA-Z0-9_]@[a-zA-Z0-9_][a-zA-Z0-9_]/xxxx@xx/g'
```

I found this easier to develop with.
Automated tests can now test for specific email adresses.